# Don't repeat arguments for similar functions or methods

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

By "similar" I mean the functions that are supposed to be used in same places.
They usually accept the same arguments. An event listeners would be an example.
But it's not a problem for them. They usually have only 1 argument - `event` or
`e` would do the work. What about a method of a class you extended
from a framework that you're using. It has 6 or 7 arguments. Also you need to
define this multiple times. Not 7 of them are used in every method of course.

The best way to go with this is to write `methodA(...args)` and then
`let myArg = args[5]`. But including this in other methods too and for each
arguments you're using. In every method. They're the exact same methods. Hope
I could expressed.

This discourages developers from writing what could be more modular code.

To make myself clear, I wrote a few examples in JavaScript.

```js
// current possible way
const compute = opt => console.log(`computations have done for ${opt}`)

class Lazy extends Object {
    methodA(opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4) {
        // methodA here
        return compute(opt2)
    }

    methodB(opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4) {
        // methodB here
        return compute(opt3)
    }
}

let lazy = new Lazy()

lazy.methodA(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The best way I could came up is to use a switch-case statement in one giant
method. Yeah not the greatest idea but eliminates the repeating
argument definitions.

```js
// solves the problem but idk
const compute = opt => console.log(`computations have done for ${opt}`)

class Lazy {
    access(method, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4) {
        switch (method) {
            case "methodA":
                // methodA goes here
                return compute(opt2)

            case "methodB":
                // methodB goes here
                return compute(opt3)
        }
    }
}

let lazy = new Lazy()

lazy.access("methodA", 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

if needed, `super.access(...arguments)` right before switch statement will call the super `access` with needed method and opts.

And here's my dreams about the problem - multi function definator to use
same named arguments

```js
// the dream
const compute = opt => console.log(`computations have done for ${opt}`)

let myLazy = arged(opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4) {
    methodA: {
        return compute(opt2)
    }
    methodB: {
        return compute(opt4)
    }
}

myLazy.methodA(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The `arged` will make this behave like `methodA(opt1,..){..`. It's so simple thing that a preprocessor can be written too. I also know it's not an easy thing to add some stuff to a language. I mean JS doesn't even have decorators. Which this technique would be effective as:

```js
// Almost the same with switch but that would be nice to have different methods instead of big switch.  
@path("/posts/:id")
class MyRest extends SomeLib{
    @arged(request, response, next, params){
        get:{
            response.text("hi")
        }
        post:{
            db.doSomething(request)
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to know if there's a better way than switch? Or is there a language to deal with those arguments of the *similar functions*? I'm interested.

I thought this would be a nice discussion. If there's something wrong about my question, please let me know. Don't come up with backend solutions, I just used it to make an analogy :D Thanks for your time <3

Comment: If a function has lots of arguments, it's often better to make it take a single argument that's an object.

Comment: "I thought this would be a nice discussion." Stack Overflow is not for discussions. It is for questions and answers. If you want discussion, hit up a forum or our own [chat]. "Better" is a distinctly subjective question also.

Comment: @HereticMonkey please read the whole *question* rather than a sentence

Comment: @Barmar I agree. but to use them, I have to deconstruct it. when there's so many methods, it gets annoying. I want it cuz I wanna make a stuff that has so many lazy evaluations. some times less than 10 lines. adding 4 other lines to deconstruct or 7-8 arguments to grab it from there just makes me sacrifice the performance benefit.

Comment: I did -- read the whole *comment* rather than a sentence. Indeed, I was responding to the very next sentence, "If there's something wrong about my question, please let me know." I let you know; apparently you didn't actually want to know.

Comment: @HereticMonkey "It is for questions and answers." isn't my _question_ a question? One paragraph of useless comments... We could be talking about _the question_

Answer (score 0):

Your switch example could be written like this.

- Return a proxy from a constructor.
- Do anything you want in the proxy - in our case map you methods.
- Return any wrapper functions you like even other proxies. In our case we do some mapping between the methods' names and the argument list.
- Btw `arguments` is a lot faster than `(...args)` if you have a huge argument list like spreading a big array.

```js
// solves the problem but idk
const compute = opt => console.log(`computations have done for ${opt}`)

class Lazy {
  constructor(){
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop){
        const idx = ['methodA', 'methodB'].indexOf(prop);
        if(idx > -1){
          return function(){
            return compute(arguments[idx + 1]);
          }
        }
        return target[prop];
      }
    });
  }
}

let lazy = new Lazy()

lazy.methodA(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: The context of the method doesn't matter. It's not about calling `compute` with a specific indexed argument. It's about reaching the arguments without redefining it for every method. In Switch-case I can basically drop a `compute(opt4)` at the end of the "`methodA`". Just like a normal method. But your snippet is only valid for very specific scenarios where reaching the arguments isn't even a problem. Switch could also be written with proxies, but I considered it as just a "cool way to pass a string argument".